# Don't KYC - is it legal/legit to have a crypto card without KYC checks?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency, visa, mastercard, know-your-customer

I recently found out about this service, called "[Don't KYC](https://dontkyc.com/)" that has its own cryptocurrency promises to provide customers with cryptocurrency Visa/Mastercard debit cards (i.e. charge your card with a cryptocurrency, then spend the fiat equivalent to that via the Visa/Mastercard network).

Not really a groundbreaking idea, except that this offering claims to not do Know Your Customer (KYC) procedures. From a privacy perspective, this would be a very sought after option, if one considers the [high likelihood of data breaches](https://www.crn.com/slide-shows/security/the-10-biggest-data-breaches-of-2021), especially if one uses such a card only for small purchases or at shady vendors.

My question is: With all the regulations (and I'm sure there are *a lot*) surrounding access of companies to the Visa/Mastercard network, how is it possible for a company to avoid KYC checks? Can such an offering even be legit? Either they are

- using some really clever workaround (if yes, which one)
- using a loophole in the law (if yes, which one; so that I can assess the risk of it being closed soon)
- a scam.

**EDIT** I had a look at recently updated [their ecosystem and tokenomics](https://docs.dontkyc.com/the-dkyc-ecosystem/dpay). It seems they have some ideas going on, so *if* they are a scam, they're not a overt. From my understanding, they seem to want to become the "Visa/Mastercard of crypto" in the sense of offering anonymous card and giving merchants POS systems so that you can pay with a crypto-loaded card easily and directly, like you would do with a Visa card. At least this would explain how they can be KYC-less; I'll also update my title to reflect this accordingly.

*But this raises the question whether it's legal for merchants to accept crypto POS system where people can pay with crypto card, or NFC-based apps from their phone?*
At the same time, this idea does not sound thaaat revolutionary; more interesting in this regard are their tokenomics, which sound interesting (make the coin deflationary as more people transact), but experience seems to show that this can blow up in peoples faces if not done properly. Hopefully they have implemented it carefully.

Comment: What are these websites? The first one doesn't even come up, is it Russian?

Comment: More importantly than violating KYC laws this likely violates the card issuer's contract with Visa/Mastercard. As soon as the payment network figures this out, the cards will be useless. So my guess would be a scam (works great here because crypto transactions are not reversible), and/or using stolen cards.

Comment: I'm curious about the censoring that is going on here; I don't understand why it is necessary to remove the CNN link regarding data breaches. You seem to have something against posting legitimate (!) sources. Or would you consider CNN to be "fake news"?...

Comment: It's not C*N*N, it's C*R*N, but there's nothing obviously spammy about it so I put it back.

Comment: Instead of focusing on KYC, I'd be more worried about (my newly invented) **KYS** (Know Your Supplier). Unless I knew who _they_ were, and was assured of _their_ reputation, I wouldn't deal with a company that loads cards with crypto and bypasses KYC!

Comment: @TripeHound I just added some new info to my question. Since this is designed for small purchases ("a pizza") I think the **KYS** risk is minimal honestly. Also, I'm pretty sure you don't know exactly where Visa has its headquarters (of course, you'll be Googling now) or other objective info that make it trustworthy. You trust them, because your friends do, not because you **know** Visa. In this regard Don't KYC is not that bad, **if** you use it for the right purpose (using it as a savings account would not be the right purpose).

Comment: "It seems they have some ideas going on, so if they are a scam, they're not a overt." Yes, that's what many people said about the Terra crypto ecosystem just before it collapsed.

Comment: If it were me I'd remove most of the paragraph related to data breaches, frankly, the question doesn't benefit any from the editorializing. It's a fairly simple question with a simple answer, doesn't need either the edit or the "why".

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Banks also collapse, just on longer time scales. Most things are a scam, and the good ones are legal scam and not overt ones (think, for example, about the incentives of giving people "cheap" mobile phones with outrageous hidden subscription fees; that's a scam, legal and not totally overt). So my point is valid.

Comment: @Joe It's necessary, because people consistently assume criminal motives which bother the heck out of me. There were some comments along these lines which seem to have been deleted. Therefore it needs to be clearly stated that there are other perfectly legitimate reasons to enable KYC-less small sum money transfer, one of the reaons being protecting oneself from said breaches.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a pre-paid Visa/MC debit card. [Pre-paid Visa cards holding less than $1000 are not subject to KYC](https://usa.visa.com/content/dam/VCOM/download/corporate/media/prepaid-reloadable-card-fact-sheet.pdf). According to the "Don't KYC" web site you linked to, they charge a 6% transaction fee for purchases. This is ten times what you'd typically pay for a pre-paid Visa card on Amazon for example. It also looks like you'd be exposed to the volatility of the "Don't KYC" token, which as of August 2022 has fallen to less than 1/100 of its peak value in Nov. 2021.

If you want anonymity just use cash for pizza, or buy gift cards or non-reloadable Visa debit cards for cash. The crypto angle is just a red-herring, or maybe an opportunity for grift.

Comment: Vague information that KYC *in theory* is not required to get a pre-paid Visa card is not helpful. Show me a specific prepaid Visa card vendor (preferably in Europe) that allows one to buy a card without KYC. I take to mean "without KYC" to me **at most** required to register with an email and a name. No telephone number should be required, nor any ID upload, nor any physical address (though store pick-up or delivery to a self-service locker/hub, as Amazon uses in many countries, is ok). [...]

Comment: This immediately raises the question how to pay for such a prepaid card in a KYC-less manner. Paying with another credit card obviously defeats the entire purpose, so only cash payments and crypto payments remain (hence your statement on the "crypto angle being a red herring" is not accurate).  I think you will be *very* hard pressed to find a company that allows all of this (it turns out that until a few years ago, there was a such a service apparently in Austria, where you could pay at gas stations and the like and get a top-up receipt with a credit card code on it, but it's gone now).